# C# Problem setting Label Content in WPF App From Separate Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, delegates, dispatcher

I have a window that contains a label (player1). I also have a class that gathers data asynchronously in the background inside a thread. When that data has been gathered, I want to changed the content of my label. Since the label was created by the UI and I'm trying to edit it from another thread, I tried using Dispatcher. However, after hours of trying and different examples, I can't get it to work. In it's most simple form below, the method dispatchP1 changes the value of player1 when called from my main window. However, it doesn't work when called from my class. Also, I don't receive an error or anything.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();

public void dispatchP1()
 {
 player1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(p1SetContent));
 }

public void p1SetContent()
 {
 player1.Content = "text";
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't seem particularly problematic - but WPF has a habit of swallowing exceptions. In your App.xaml, you can handle the event DispatcherUnhandledException and put a breakpoint in there to determine if it is really throwing an exception or not.

Comment: I added DispatcherUnhandledException to my App.xaml and specified a method to catch it, but I'm still not getting an error from that code.

Comment: Your projects works, but when I call it from an inherited class it doesn't. The p1SetContent function is called, but the Content of player1 is never changed. If I check the property of player1.Content, it returns the updated value, but it is never reflected in the UI.

Comment: What is being inherited? MainWindow (in the case of my example)?

Comment: In the case of your example, MainWindow is being inherited by the separate class. Also, what version of VS are you using. I had a couple of errors when I tried to load your project, but your code works just fine.

Comment: That's because by inheriting, they have different dispatchers and different owners. You're setting the player1.Content on the inherited window, not the parent. That's why it appears to do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out. I made my class non-inherited, and then passed the parent window to the class constructor so I could reference the parent.

Comment: That'll do it, generally inheritance of windows only causes problems unless you are using it to actually display another window.

Comment: Yeah, I've discovered that. The inheritance wasn't actually necessary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can use anonymous delegates?

```
player1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
{
   player1.Content = "text";
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I've since done that, but I wanted to make sure it was working before making my code more concise/less readable.